# What is the biblical basis for the belief that Papal supremacy can be passed on from person to person over time?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, papacy, peter

I know that Matthew 16:18 is commonly cited as the biblical basis for the [Papal supremacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_supremacy) of Peter, who is viewed by Catholics as the first Pope. However, what is not yet clear to me is the biblical basis for the belief that such authority can be passed on from person to person over the generations. My understanding is that all the apostles were chosen by Jesus, including the apostle Paul, who had a supernatural Christophany in his way to Damascus. So, my immediate impression would be that all individuals in positions of power/authority in the Bible were chosen by God directly, not by people, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

What is the biblical basis for the belief that the Papal supremacy can be passed on from person to person over time?

Comment: I don't think biblical basis alone can answer this question, as I think the source of this doctrine lies within the Catholic understanding of [the deposit of faith](https://www.catholicfaithandreason.org/the-deposit-of-faith-and-the-holy-spirit-of-god.html).  Consequently, tagging this Q with both `catholicism` and `biblical-basis` seems ill-advised and contradictory, but I would invite the moderators opinion on this.

Comment: How does the Wikipedia link you employed not answer your question?

Comment: @KenGraham - It cites Matthew, but that only supports Peter's authority (as I explain in the question). What is missing is the biblical basis for the passing on of such authority from person to person (which is the focus of my question).